# Mobile Safari - event.target in touch event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mobile-safari

I would like to have the target when a touch something on the screen of my iPad.
But unfortunately it always returns the `currentTarget`, never the target.

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);

function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {

  if (event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div" || event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "canvas") {
      // do someting
  }
  else
  {
     // do something else
  }

}
```

But `event.target.tagName` is always `"HTML"`. But never the real element I touched, for example an anchor tag or a div.

How do I get the real element I touched?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try the "event.touches" array, which will have one entry for each finger currently down, with the "target" value referencing the DOM element touched.

```
function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {
    if (event.touches[0] && event.touches[0].target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div") {
        // do someting
    }
}
```

However, I should note that I was unable to duplicate the original issue; when I tried it, event.target referred to the touched div as intended. You might also check your CSS and/or JS plugins that might be interfering with event bubbling.

Comment: And you can visit this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchEventClassReference/TouchEvent/TouchEvent.html) for the reference of TouchEvent and this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/TouchClassReference/Touch/Touch.html) for the reference of Touch.