# Phonegap jQuery event.target Not working

Tags: jquery, ipad, cordova, event-handling

I have PhoneGap-iOS Application for iPad where User will get Logout Popup as shown in Image below.

[image: Logout popup]

I want this popup to hide when User clicks on Body. 
My `code` which works on native browser is **not working** on `iPad Simulator`.

```
$("body").ClickOrTouch(function (evt) {
    if (!(evt.target.id == "launchUsername") {
        $('#launchLogout').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you try on a real iDevice?

Comment: I have tested it on Real Device too..

Answer (score 3):

In iPhone, iPad devices click event will work in anchor tag only not for span or div tags, so try this it will work.

```
$("body").on('click touchend', function (evt) {
  if (!(evt.target.id == "launchUsername") {
    $('#launchLogout').hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `event.touches[0].target` can do it on mobile safari ( You've got the touches array in order to manage multitouch events, one by finger). 
As discussed in this topic : [Mobile Safari - event.target in touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580267/mobile-safari-event-target-in-touch-event)

But I think it's worth to try with [jquery-ui-touch-punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/).

It's what I use to manage touch events with jquery on mobile web app (such as cordova/phonegap)

Very simple : simply adding this library makes any touh event behave like mouse events.

(touch down/up => mouse down/up,  single press => click  etc... )

Comment: I will try to use jquery-ui-touch-punch. But I wanted to know what went wrong with above code when I test it on iPad Simulator

Comment: hmm not sure if its  'clickOrTouch'  without the capital 'C' ?

Comment: the ClickOrTouch Event gets executed. Just the event.target shows undefined every time.

Comment: yep, according to jquery documentation, target should be normalized for cross-browser...   source : http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DEvents%2FjQuery.Event%26redirect%3Dno#event.target)

Comment: So How can i do that normalization? any suggestions

Comment: hmm maybe event.touches[0].target will do the trick : on mobile safari you can get one touch event by finger touching the screen.  more on this with this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580267/mobile-safari-event-target-in-touch-event

Answer (score 2):

```
$("body").on('touchend', function (evt) {
    if (!(evt.target.id == "launchUsername") {
        $('#launchLogout').hide();
    }else{
evt.stopPropagation();

}


});
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried a different event yet? something like that maybe?

```
$("body").on('touchend', function (evt) {
    if (!(evt.target.id == "launchUsername") {
        $('#launchLogout').hide();
    }
});
```