# Getting Mobile Menu to stay open when clicking submenu - Slicknav

Tags: jquery, mobile, menu, onclick, slicknav

I'm using Slicknav: http://slicknav.com/

I almost have all the behavior right but not quite. I want the menu to close whenever someone clicks outside of it, which I got, except that now that I enforced that, the menu closes when I try to open a submenu. I need to get it to where the whole menu stays open when clicking a submenu, and also closes when someone clicks outside of the menu (anywhere else on the page). Any ideas?

```
<ul id="menu">

<li><a href="">link</a></li>
<li><a href="">link</a></li>

<li>
<a href="">Submenu</a>

<ul>
<li><a href="">Submenu link</a></li>
<li><a href="">Submenu link</a></li>
<li><a href="">Submenu link</a></li>
</ul>

</li>

<li><a href="">link</a></li>
<li><a href="">link</a></li>

</ul>


<script src="slicknav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu').slicknav({
label:'',
closeOnClick:true
});
});

/* close menu on outside click*/
$("div, html").on("click", function (event) { 
event.stopPropagation();
if(!$(event.target).hasClass("#menu a") && 
!$(event.target).hasClass("ul.slicknav_nav li a") && 
!$(event.target).hasClass("slicknav_menutxt") && 
!$(event.target).hasClass("slicknav_icon") && 
!$(event.target).hasClass("slicknav_icon-bar") &&
!$(event.target).hasClass("slicknav_btn")) {   
$("#menu").slicknav('close'); 
}
});
</script>
```

This fixed it:

```
document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {
    if (event.touches[0] && event.touches[0].target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "div") {
        $("#menu").slicknav('close');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your click handler to

```
/* close menu on outside click*/
$("html").on("click", function (event) {
    if ($(".slicknav_menu").has(event.target).length === 0)
        $("#menu").slicknav('close');
});
```

Basically check if the target is within the menu, and don't close it if it is. If you have multiple instances of menu on the page, you will have to change your selector appropriately.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. It works perfectly on my Android, but unfortunately not on my Ipad. Not sure what to do about ios devices.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580267/mobile-safari-event-target-in-touch-event